# How to access native iOS file system using Sencha touch 2 alone

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, filesystems, sencha-touch

I am working on an Sencha Touch application.

There is a use case in this application where I need to modify text file and save it again on iOS device.

As I've deal with almost 300-400 MB of data, so I can't use local storage here(Please correct me if I am wrong).

Here, I don't want to use Phonegap or any other framework to access native file system.

Could you please tell me, how I can access native filesystem using Sencha touch alone.

Answer (score 0):

Since Sencha is a platform for building HTML5 apps (thus, websites) you cannot access the native iOS file system, unless you use Sencha SDK Tools and native packaging (but you don't seem to want to use that).